# Make up $a$, $b$, and $c$ such that $f(x)=\frac{1}{ax^2+bx+c}$ is even and positive

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Make up numbers for $a$, $b$ and $c$ to make this true: the function $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{ax^2 + bx +c}$ has even symmetry and is entirely above the x-axis.

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: i dont know how to even start it

Answer (score 4):

HINT: $f$ has even symmetry if
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{ax^2 + bx + c} = f(-x) = \frac{1}{ax^2 - bx + c} $$
for all $x$.  That is,
$$ ax^2 - bx + c = ax^2 + bx + c $$
for all $x$.  This immediately implies $b = \_$?  What happens if you evaluate the expression at $x = 1$?

---

EDIT:
We've found that $b = 0$.  Now $f(x) = \frac{1}{ax^2 + c} > 0$ for all $x$.  We must have $c > 0$, for otherwise $f(0) = \frac{1}{c} < 0$ (or is undefined if $c = 0$), which we are trying to avoid.  I claim that $a \geq 0$.  To see this, suppose $a < 0$.  Then we may choose $x$ large enough so that $ax^2 + c < 0$, which would imply $\frac{1}{ax^2 + c} < 0$, which we are trying to avoid.

Comment: so do i just solve for one variable and then sub that into the original equation and solve for the next variable? does that imply that b= 0

Comment: You want to find the $a$, $b$, and $c$.  Evaluate the second expression at $x = 1$ and you should be able to solve for $b$.

Comment: i got b = 0, is that right?

Comment: That's right.  Now you can't say anything about $a$ and $c$ from here.  But you know that $f(x) > 0$.  This implies $\frac{1}{ax^2 + c} > 0$ for all $x$.  Are you looking for specific $a$ and $c$?  If so, try $a = 1$ and $c = 1$?

Comment: im looking for all values of a , c when they are above the x- axis and even symmetry, there are infinite number of solutions but im just looking for one of them

Comment: I added an edit to give an answer for $a$ and $c$.